# FireBase value not printing properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get all the values of a collection so I did

```
const q = query(collection(db, "IPAddresses"));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var newAddress = document.createElement("Label");
            newAddress.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(doc.data());
            AddressDiv.appendChild(newAddress);
        });
```

The only issue is the values show like this

```
{"IPAddresses":"Address"}{"IPAddresses":"Address"}{"IPAddresses":"Address"}
```

I need it like this

```
"Address" "Address" "Address"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a value of a specific field then set that value as `innerHTML`:

```
newAddress.innerHTML = doc.data().IPAddresses; // instead of JSON.stringify(doc.data())
```